# On Proving that $e^x$ is continuous at $0$ utilizing a limit result.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, exponential-function

I was assigned the task to prove that $e^x$ is continuous in $x=0$ utilizing the fact that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^x - 1} {x} = 1 $$

I think I am supposed to show that from the fact that for every $\epsilon >0$ I can choose a $\delta \in R$ s.t.  $|x| < \delta \implies | \frac{e^x - 1} {x} - 1| < \epsilon $ that even $|e^x - 1|$ can be made less than $\epsilon$.

I wrote that $$ \frac{|e^x - 1| - |x|} {|x|}  \le|\frac{e^x - 1} {x} - 1| < \epsilon$$

But I can't find the inequality I would like to be true, How could I do?

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, we are given that there eixts $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x|<\delta$ implies $\left|\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1\right|<\epsilon$.
So $|e^x-(1+x)|<|x|\epsilon$ for such $x$.
If we impose additionally that $|x|<\frac12$, this gives us 
$|e^x-(1+x)|<\frac\epsilon2$, so that if we (additionally again) impose the condition $|x|<\frac\epsilon2$ we obtain
$$|e^x-1|\le |e^x-1|+|x|<\frac\epsilon2+|x|<\epsilon $$
As $e^0=1$ it follows that $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous at $0$.

---

Actually, if we consider $f(x)=e^x$, note that that we want to show that $f$ is continuos at a point where we are given that $f'$ exists. This is always the case.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $e^0=1$?

Using your notation, it follows that 
$$
|e^x-1|<(1+ϵ)·|x|
$$
which gives you local Lipschitz continuity.